# CLR loading assembly with friendly name

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

In my application, I have two required assemblies(third party) in different app paths. These assemblies have different versions, publickeytoken but same assembly name. During the run time of the application, CLR throws the exception

> *Could not load file or assembly** 'AssemblyName, Version=x.x.x.x, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies.
>   The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)*

Why doesnt CLR consider assembly's four parameter to load it exact assembly?
Is there any way to load assembly by considering all four parameters.

Comment: If you need to load 2 different versions you have to load them into the different AppDomains. If you need only one - proceed with Neel's solution

Comment: You are asking to make DLL Hell a feature for your program.  I doubt you know what kind of hell you are asking for.  You must use `<bindingRedirect>` in the app.exe.config file to enter hell.  Don't do it, rebuild the program with a correct reference assembly instead.